# Prove by $\epsilon-\delta$ that as $x \to 3,\space 5x\to15$

Tags: limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Prove by an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument that as $x \to 3,\space 5x\to15.$

My workings:

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given such that $\mid \ 5x-15\mid=5\mid x-3\mid<\epsilon$

Thus with $\epsilon=5\delta,\space \mid5x-15\mid<\epsilon$ whenever $\mid \ x-3\mid<\delta$

Therefore the definition of lim$_{x\to3} \ 5x=15\space$  is satisfied. *QED*

Did I prove this correctly? Thank you guys!

Comment: You do not start with an $ε>0$ such that $ |5x-15|<ε$, you assume an $ε>0$ is given and you try to find an appropriate $δ>0$ (in our case $δ= 5ε$) such that $ |5x-15|<ε $, whenever $|x-3|<δ$.

Answer (score 2):

You have a *proof sketch* but you do not have a proper proof. Follow the steps in [this link](http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/DeltaEpsilonProofs03.htm) to write  a formal proof.

Suppose $\epsilon > 0$ has been provided. Define $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{5}$. Since $\epsilon > 0$, then we also have $\delta > 0$.

Now for every $x$, the expression $0 < |x - c|  < \delta$ implies $|x - 3| < \frac{\epsilon}{5}$. Can you get to the conclusion from here?